# Cordova runtime permissions

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

I'm trying to get the user to enable the location group permission for my app with Cordova's hasPermission/requestPermission methods, but the results are confusing...

When I call hasPermission with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, it always returns true. Calling this on Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION seems to return true/false appropriately.

Calling requestPermission with Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION doesn't present a system dialog, so I'm calling this with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to get the dialog.

The dialog Allow button turns on the Location group permission for my app and calls onRequestPermissionResult with PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, but the Deny button also returns ...GRANTED, leaving the Location group permission off.

For illustration, here's my current code:

```
private void checkPermissions() {
    if (!cordova.hasPermission(Manifest.permission_group.LOCATION)) {
        cordova.requestPermission(this, PERMISSION_RUNTIME_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
    if (permissions.length != 1 || grantResults.length != 1 || !Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.equals(permissions[0])) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected permission results " + Arrays.toString(permissions) + ", " + Arrays.toString(grantResults));
    }
    int result = grantResults[0];
    String action = null;
    switch (result) {
        case PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            action = Constants.ACTION_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_DENIED;
            break;
        case PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED:
            action = Constants.ACTION_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected permission result int " + result);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(action);
    i.putExtra("permission", Constants.EXTRA_RUNTIME_PERMISSION_NOTIFICATION_ID);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

What's the right way to handle this? Sometimes using an individual permission and sometimes using a group with these methods doesn't seem right - I would expect this to be consistent. My guess is that the PERMISSION_GRANTED after the DENY button is pushed on the dialog is because I'm requesting an individual permission, which is on even though the group is off; is there a way to detect that the user denied the request?

I have a lot of questions there which basically boil down to "how do I either get the user to enable the Location group permission when it's off or know when they decline"?

If it helps, my android-targetSdkVersion is set to 22, and I'm using Cordova 6.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it helps, my android-targetSdkVersion is set to 22, and I'm using Cordova 6.1.1.

Android run-time permissions were only introduced in API **23**, so if your android-targetSdkVersion is set to **22**, run-time permissions code will always return GRANTED for any permission, since permissions are granted at installation time via the manifest.

However, if your app **is** displaying runtime permissions dialogs, I'm guessing that you must be building against API 23 and using `cordova-android@5+` for the Android platform.

Regarding permission groups vs individual permissions, you should read the [Android documentation regarding runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html):

> The dialog box shown by the system describes the permission group your app needs access to; it does not list the specific permission. For example, if you request the READ_CONTACTS permission, the system dialog box just says your app needs access to the device's contacts. The user only needs to grant permission once for each permission group. If your app requests any other permissions in that group (that are listed in your app manifest), the system automatically grants them. When you request the permission, the system calls your onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method and passes PERMISSION_GRANTED, the same way it would if the user had explicitly granted your request through the system dialog box.

So in your case, requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` grants access to all permissions in the `LOCATION` group (you can find the full list of groups and permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups)).

> the Deny button also returns ...GRANTED, leaving the Location group permission off.

This should not return GRANTED. If the Deny button is pressed, access will be DENIED to that entire permission group (including the requested permission). The logic in your code snippet looks OK to handle this, so I would use the step-through debugger in Android Studio to see exactly what is happening in your code here.

Comment: I suspect the GRANTED return from the Deny button is because it's returning the API 22 value of true for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.